# Navigation bar disappears in Internet Explorer

Tags: css, html, wordpress, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I've recently completed my first custom-built Wordpress website, based on Automattic's Toolbox theme, and am in the process of testing it. I'm having some strange issues with IE 6-8 which I've not experienced before - the entire navigation bar, including the background colour, disappears leaving only the logo. None of the navigation links show up, nor does the button which triggers the menu dropdown on small screen sizes.

The website is http://fpsl.eu , and I'm pretty much stumped. I don't think it's a JS issue since it works fine in Firefox and Chrome without JS. An HTML5 shiv comes preinstalled with Toolbox so I don't *think* it's a compatibility issue in that respect...but maybe I'm wrong, and I don't know how to check!

(I'm using Browserstack to test and am actually wondering if its rendering is accurate - my portfolio website which I tested extensively a few months ago - [www.dearjackalope.com](http://www.dearjackalope.com) - is now causing Browserstack's IE virtual machine to hang, despite my having made no major changes other than adding content - this is a separate issue I guess, but it makes me unsure as to whether all my sites are breaking at once or if it's just Browserstack being moody!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am checking your site(http://fpsl.eu/) in ie7,8 and 9. It's working properly.

Answer (score 0):

1) Fix your markup code errors; they may not be the whole trouble, but fix them first: [[Invalid] Markup Validation of  fpsl.eu  - W3C Markup Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A//fpsl.eu/&doctype=Inline&ss=1&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator/1.654). Scroll down in the validation report to see line numbers and source code. Start fixing the code errors and revalidate.

2) You need native IE7+ - not Browsershots - to fully test IE. Find a Windows PC to test with and use [**F12 dev tools in IE**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673541(v=vs.85).aspx) to emulate other versions.

3) Forget IE6; it's dead.

Comment: I've fixed the validation errors (which I thought I'd already done but evidently hadn't, there were heaps of them!) and now every page except for the blog validates. Still having the same problem. I evidently need to go and hunt down a PC, I'm just a bit baffled because it's such a peculiar error - I can't see what would cause the navigation background to vanish.